# How to redirect child process output to stderr?

Tags: rust, io-redirection

I am trying to start a process with the [`Command`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Command.html) API and redirect its standard output to standard error. The following fails:

```
Command::new("tput").arg("rc")
    .stdout(io::stderr())
    .status()
    .expect("failed to run tput");
```

because `Command::new("tput").arg("rc").stdout(<XXX>)` expects a `std::process::Stdio`:

```
expected struct `std::process::Stdio`, found struct `std::io::Stderr`
```

The equivalent in Bash would probably be `tput rc > /dev/stderr`.

I would like to know how to do this properly.

Comment: Briefly looking at the API I'd say this is not possible. Perhaps an issue should be raised for this where the `stdout` method could accept a `Writer` instance instead?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of Rust 1.15.0, `Stdio` doesn't expose this functionality in a portable API, but there are platform-specific extension traits that you can use for this purpose.

On Unix-like platforms, [the `std::os::unix::io::FromRawFd` trait is implemented on `Stdio`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Stdio.html#implementations). This trait provides a single method, `from_raw_fd`, that can turn a file descriptor into the type that implements the trait. Since standard error is defined as file descriptor 2, you could simply use `.stdout(Stdio::from_raw_fd(2))`.

On Windows, [there's a similar trait called `FromRawHandle` implemented on `Stdio`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/a797b6e2feb1c6cd60868a2d3b59029a0ca5df64/src/libstd/sys/windows/ext/process.rs#L20-L27). Unfortunately, it's not listed in the online documentation; it only contains the Unix-specific variants. You would call `GetStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE)` to obtain a handle to the standard error.

Answer (score 1):

This worked on linux. Pulling in the [`AsFd`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/os/fd/trait.AsFd.html) trait allows us to get a [`BorrowedFd`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/os/fd/struct.BorrowedFd.html) from `stderr`.
The [`try_clone_to_owned`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/os/fd/struct.BorrowedFd.html#method.try_clone_to_owned) method was hard to find, but it gives a [`OwnedFd`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/os/fd/struct.OwnedFd.html) which can automatically convert into a [`process::Stdio`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Stdio.html#impl-From%3COwnedFd%3E-for-Stdio), the type required to configure [`stderr`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Command.html#method.stderr) of child processes.

```rust
use std::os::fd::AsFd;

let stderr = std::io::stderr().as_fd().try_clone_to_owned()?;
std::process::Command::new("terraform")
    .arg("fmt")
    .arg(&outpath)
    .stdout(stderr)
    .status()
    .unwrap_or_else(|_| panic!("terraform fmt failed: {:?}", outpath));
```

---

Compacted into a function:

```rust
fn stderr() -> Result<std::process::Stdio, Error> {
    use std::os::fd::AsFd;
    let stderr = std::io::stderr().as_fd().try_clone_to_owned()?;
    Ok(stderr.into())
}
```